# How to send keyboard input to another program

Tags: c

I have a text file located on desktop:

spam.txt

Inside this file has lines of strings, and I want to read each line and send the same keyboard input to another program. For example:

spam.txt contains:

Hello World!

When I execute this program it will keyboard input to another program:

```
keyboardinput("H")
keyboardinput("e")
keyboardinput("l")
```

... and so on.

Comment: Are you looking to *literally* simulate keypresses, or do you just want the second program to see that output on it's standard input stream (e.g. for use with something like `scanf`)?

Comment: It seems you want a macro utility like [AutoHotKey](https://www.autohotkey.com/).

Comment: Use a pipe.  For windows https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html, for Linux https://opensource.com/article/18/8/introduction-pipes-linux

Comment: @0x5453 i want to literally simulate a keypress because i want to create a script that types in a game.

Comment: @AyushParikh Thanks for clarifying.  I agree with Dour that AutoHotKey is a good tool for this.  If you *really* want to write everything yourself, you can still use AHK for reference since they are [open source](https://github.com/AutoHotkey/AutoHotkey) (though note that they use C++ instead of C).